# Fast way substracting GIS Layers in R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, rgdal

I'm trying to calculate a difference layer in R using the packages rgeos, rgdal and so on. It basically consists of a base country layer out of which I would like to cut out forests, populated areas, lakes, roads, etc so that I get a difference layer which consists of the the area of the country that is not overlapped by the beformentioned layers. Only, already the forest layer alone consists of a couple of thousand polygons, and I've been running `gDifference()` for hours without getting to a result. Not an ideal set up for playing around with how much terrain I would like to cut out. Is there any possibility to speed up the process? Im thinking: convert to raster-stack or so? Much obliged for any ideas!

In the image below, I would like to keep the gray areas (cut out polygon layers and buffered line layers).

[image: Different overlapping layers]

Comment: Could you tell us a little about the hardware you're working with (i.e., RAM, number of processors)? Could you break up all of the geometries into several pieces (say, by clipping each polygon to four smaller bounding boxes) then perform the tasks in parallel?

Comment: I sure could! I'm working on a i5-4300U CPU @ 1.9 GHz 2.5 GHz duocore with 8 Gbit RAM. There's a possibility to set it up on a 64Gbit RAM and 6 core CPU. I'm not to familiar with how hardware affects calculations. Would a larger RAM always speed up things? Or is there a certain threshold after which effects would not be noticeable? I guess I could parallelise it, but I would be very happy if you could point me in the right direction as how to do that. I've heard of it, but have never done anything like that for R calculations before. Thanks!

Comment: What's the format of your "base" layer ? A vector or a raster ? Also, two things that could speed-up things could be dissolving the polygons beforehand based on common attributes, and maybe simplifying geometries (If you can afford some loss in "accuracy")

Comment: When I've run into this problem, aggregating a raster and simplifying a vector required a significant amount of time, but your case may be different. I think @LorenzoBusetto's suggestion of dissolving the polygons sounds like a good bet. Parallelization R can be pretty simple. Check out the parallel and foreach packages. You'll want to work on the more powerful machine, though, since working with spatial objects in parallel tends to require a lot of RAM. The 4 additional cores would be nice as well.

Comment: @LorerenzoBusetto My base layer is vector. I might check out the overlay of the difference vector layer with a raster layer later, but the first step would be to get the areas in question (in form of polygons). I'll try your dissolving idea!

Comment: @coletl , thanks, I'll try to parallelize and set it up on a faster machine. I hope to be able to make some speed comparisons and post those in here.

Comment: I see now that rather than dissolving you could also merge everything in a single mullyypolygon. That way you will further reduce the number of poles to subtract.